# Unable to open URL: Add app to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your info.plist

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking

I am trying to navigate back to the app from webpage, I am using deep linking with React Native. The app.js is below:

```
  const linking = {
    prefixes: [
      'helloapp://'
    ],
    config: {
      screens: {
        CreditAnswer: 'Answer'
      }
    },
  };
```

The added LSApplication to the info.plist is here:

```
 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                <string>hello app</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>hello app</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>hello app</string>
        </array>
```

Then the added `Bool` to the `AppDelegate.m` file

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

@end
```

Please help me I really cannot see what is wrong.